# MySQL - Inserting Primary Key from one table to another (Foreign Key)

Tags: mysql, jsp

Although this question has been asked, It hasn't really adapted to how I wanted it to work for me, as i keep receiving errors.

I have a table: Customer_orders which i insert values into:

```
<sql:update var="count">
    insert into customer_order (order_date,delivered ,shipping_date,customer_number ) 
    values ( SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 17 DAY), 1, SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY), <%= session.getAttribute( "username" ) %> ); 
    </sql:update>
```

Now this customer_order has PRIMARY KEY called "Order Number" that auto increments

I want to take this order_number and insert it into a table, I tried something like:

```
<sql:update var="count">
insert into order_item (item_code,value,order_number,quantity)
values( "<%= request.getParameter( "item_code" ) %>", "<%= request.getParameter( "item_price" ) %>",customer_order(order_number),1 );
</sql:update>
```

And i even tried different ways to insert the order_number but I can't get it to work. When I created the two tables, the order_number is a foreign key in the 2nd table so I thought it would grab the value itself but didn't.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply get the last inserted id from your first query in a transaction and then insert it in another table as you like , so for that i propose this approach it may help you :

```
<sql:transaction dataSource="${snapshot}"  >
  <sql:update var="count">
       insert into customer_order (order_date,delivered ,shipping_date,customer_number ) 
       values ( SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 17 DAY), 1, SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY), <%= session.getAttribute( "username" ) %> ); 
</sql:update> 
  <sql:query var="las_inserted_id" >
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_Id
  </sql:query >
  /*now you got the last inserted id so that you can simply insert it in your new query as you like*/
<sql:update var="count">
     insert into order_item (item_code,value,order_number,quantity)
     values( "<%= request.getParameter( "item_code" ) %>", "<%= request.getParameter( "item_price" ) %>",${ las_inserted_id.rows[0].last_Id },1 );
</sql:update>
</sql:transaction>
```

**NB** : please try as much as you can to avoid sql logic code in your view !! so that it could be easy to maintain your application

Comment: What exactly does the dataSource snapshot do? Because im getting an error for that line, saying that datasource is null

Comment: the `${snapshot}` contain the conenction instace with your databse such as the driver name,  the username of databse , passowrd , url etc all those information we put them in a tag called `sql:setDataSource` which take as var the `snapshot` , any how you can customise it depending on your implementation

Comment: Any idea why it's saying that datasource is null?

Comment: it's weird !! tell me how did you executed your old queries ??  you can not execute any query before without setting the datasource !! in other words where did you set the driver , username , url , password information related to your database instance ??

Comment: Well i had a script SQL that i executed, and at the top of the script i had `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS TOSHIBA;
CREATE DATABASE TOSHIBA;
USE TOSHIBA;` Note I am using JSP/JSTL not PHP

Comment: but to execute any query you want , you should first get connection with the database !! let me see where did you did the connection here ??

Comment: Hmm, I dont have any other sort of connection to the database, because im using sql inside of jsp and i am using tomcat server as the connection to the database i guess?

Comment: Hmmmm , it's not recommended at all to insert sql logic code in JSP , but just to make sure things work , try to have a connection with database in the JSP by typing on the top this :
`<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Your_data-Base_name"
     user="username"  password="password"/>` so that you can be sure that the code i suggested to you work fine

Comment: That does the trick, thank you. I was wondering if my answer could be answers any alternative ways but this also makes sense.