# How to Add mysql foreign key from another table primary key?

Tags: php, mysql

What should I add as the second value?

I tried last id, but it is not working.

I want to add the question's primary key.

```
$connect->exec(" INSERT INTO answers(choice_option, questions_id)
                 VALUES('$choiceoption', [what goes here?])");
```

Comment: Pull the ID that result from the last query. It is not clear what driver you are using. You also appear to be open to SQL injections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Inserting Primary Key from one table to another (Foreign Key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649065/mysql-inserting-primary-key-from-one-table-to-another-foreign-key)

Comment: I still have no answer

Comment: @Mohamed You tried `LAST_INSERT_ID`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832497/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit old, maybe is Legacy code but I recommend to you that use mysql_insert_id()
if primary key: questions_id is AUTO_INCREMENT.
For example:

```
<?
  $connect->exec("INSERT INTO questions 
  (questions_points, questions_ask, answer_option, contest_id) 
  VALUES ('$questionspoints', '$questionsask', '$answeroption', '$lastid') ");
  //Get last inserted from question's table:
  $last_insert = mysql_insert_id();
  $connect->exec(" INSERT INTO answers(choice_option, questions_id)
  VALUES('$choiceoption', '$last_insert')");
 ?>
```

> Suggestion: Use mysqli or PDO instead classic mysql because is deprecated.

More information:
[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)